# Invalid Request Signature Error for accounts.register

Tags: swift, gigya

I got invalid Request signature error when tried to register using Gigya account.Registraion. I can successfully resgister a single user, then got the above error for another registraion. It will work if I chagne my app bundleID. Then I can register one more user.. Then same error got for another registration

Comment: Not enough information. Can you add a callID? steps to reproduce? What platform, and SDK you are using, etc. However, given the error itself, it seems that you are generating the signature incorrectly. The first thing I would do is verify I was using the correct secret to create the signature. If you are using an application key, this would be the application's secret, not the main account secret.